# Redirect from form submission on webpage using Code.gs?

Tags: html, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to set up a form on my webpage that will write the information submitted to the form onto the website by accessing the database and printing out what's in the database on the site. When the form is completed, it should redirect to a success page.
The issue is, I'm using google sheets and I followed this tutorial https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet to set up my Code.gs page for the sheet, in the tutorial they have a section where it automatically redirects a successful form filled out to a JSON. I want it to redirect to a different page on my website and I'm having a lot of trouble with that.

TLDR; Can't figure out how to redirect to a success page in Code.gs

Here's the original Code.gs code:

```
return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
```

and here's what I tried adding (I removed the above code and replaced it with this)

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    "<script>window.top.location.href='http://localhost:5000/formsubmit';</script>"
    );
```

I keep getting a redirect to a page that says "This application was created by another user, not by Google." whenever I fill out the form. The information in the form gets put into the google sheet, but I just can't figure out how to redirect to my /formsubmit page. Here's the code for my form:

```
<form 
        target = "_top"
        method="POST" 
        action="SCRIPT_URL">
        <input name="Costume name" type="text" placeholder="Costume Name" required>
        <input name="Rented?" type="text" placeholder="Rented?" required>
        <input name="Rentable?" type="text" placeholder="Rentable?" required>
        <input name="Costume image" type="text" placeholder="ENTER NULL" required>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
```

"SCRIPT_URL" is replaced with my script url but I'm not sure if I should share it on here, I'm fairly new to this stuff sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue! Here's a github response with my same issue https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets/issues/59.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).